# How to use Nautilus to connect davs server

Tags: linux, webdav, nautilus

I want to connect to my webserver, but the ssh is disabled, so decided to try using the webdisk service the server-provider suggested. My **Nautilus** though can't seem to be able to connect the **davs server**.

When I run it and ask to join it recognizes the davs address but when I press the "connect" button, it shows me an error saying: "unhandled error: cannot connect to destination (...)".

Whenever I try doing this as **superuser** though it doesn't even let me click on the connect button saying: **"This file server type is not recognized."**

I thought it might be due to some packages missing to handle davs connections. Can it be the problem? I'm using Nautilus 3.10.1 on Deepin Linux (which uses the ubuntu repositories). Can anyone tell me what packages do I need to install, or how do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you've found the answer yourself since Jan 2016, but for the sake of others who may search for the answer, I'll say it:

Make sure you have `davfs2` package installed.